# How to check what type a variable is?

Tags: objective-c, c

I want to know if `someVariable` is of type int or float. How would I do the check?

Edit: In code at runtime! In the IDE that would be simple. I want to know if there is some kind of typeof operator to see if you're dealing with int, float, long, char, unsigned char, long long or whatever.

Comment: cmd-double-click (in Xcode, which I assume you're using given the objective-c tag)

Comment: @Daniel Dickison: die-hards use butterflies, not Xcode.

Comment: BugAlert: Please clarify your question. Do you want to know within the source code? Do you want to know at runtime? What exactly is the situation?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you understand what you're trying to do or not, but if you do, my answer does what you asked for.

Comment: @Time Machine: No, first you have to invent the universe, then you can use your new-school butterflies, kids these days and their fancy pants tricks.

Comment: @mu is too short: no, they open their hands and let the delicate wings flap once. The disturbance ripples outward, changing the flow in the eddy currents in the upper atmosphere. Oh wait, they indeed use cosmic rays. Dammit, mu is too short. ;)

Comment: @BugAlert: Would you please show an *example* of how you want to use this? Variables in C are statically typed, so in most code you just have to look at the declaration. An exception might be if you're trying to do clever things with macros. Are you? Even if you are, variables at runtime only have one type. They can't be anything else other than what they are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if ((1?1:var)/2) {
    /* it's floating point */
} else {
    /* it's an integer */
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by what this actually does.  Won't (1 ? 1 : var) always return 1?  Then (1 ? 1 : var) / 2 would always return 0, so the variable would always evaluate to an integer.

Comment: @helixed: The type of the expression has to be a common type between `1` and `var`. (This applies to all conditional expressions.) If `var` is an integral type, `1` will be an integral type and you get zero as a result. Otherwise `1` will be a floating point type and you get non-zero as a result. Basically, you can use conditional expressions to deduce types; for a popular use in C++, [see this](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html).

Comment: Note that `(0*var+1)/2` would also work, but it evaluates `var`, and could have unwanted side effects if `var` is an expression with side effects.

Comment: Nice. However, are there any scenarios that **well-written C code** needs this?

Comment: In a sense, you never "need" it because the type is always known at some point and you could simply make different macros for the integer and float versions and call the appropriate one. Of course that gets to be a lot of combinations if you have 3 or 4 arguments that could all be different types...

Comment: As for when it's useful, I think C++ templates have pretty well established that *generic programming* is a powerful tool. Clever use of the `?:` operator makes a lot of generic programming possible in C too. Operations like `SERIALIZE()`, `SQRT()`, `LOG2()`, etc. could all have very different implementations for a floating point argument versus an integer argument, and the method I described lets you do that with a single "function" name.

Comment: In the context of [Objective-]C, this is really only useful in macros, right?  Otherwise you would know what type `var` is declared as and use that explicitly.

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps also with system-defined types. For instance `time_t` is an arithmetic type, but it's implementation-defined whether it's floating point or integral.

Comment: Even with the comment from GManNickG I don't really understand how that works, does somebody has a link or explanation? (somehow the type of 1 is set with var in the conditional expression, under what rule)

Comment: @ViktorLexington: See C11 6.5.15 Conditional operator, paragraph 5: "If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands, is the type of the result."

Answer (score 2):

Is `someVariable` an NSNumber? If it's a primitive C type (an actual `int` or `float`), then you'll already know because it can be declared as only one of those things, and the compiler (and Xcode) will enforce that. As another commenter noted, Command-Double-Click the name to find the declaration in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Since sizeof(float) == sizeof(int) (depending on platform, but on i386 and current iPhone this is valid) - i believe you can't decide during runtime whether your variable is int or float.</strike>
EDIT: Greg is right in the comment. This check doesn't really make sense.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. C is statically typed, so a variable can only have one type, determined at compile time. Variables can't change type at runtime.

Comment: The check still could make sense as part of a macro which can be applied to variables/expressions of different types.